# 2 nics, 1 subnet, 1 gateway... is it possible to make that one nic will be for physical server and second nic for Hyper-v only?

Tags: networking, nic, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

We have a WindowsServer2008R2 with Hyper-V with physical 2 nics, 1 subnet, 1 gateway..is it possible to make that one nic will be for physical server and second nic for Hyper-v only?

Thanks in advance.

Bryan

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

VMs are associated, via their settings, with a Virtual Network. A Virtual Network is associated (via Virtual Network Manager—from host computer node in Hyper-V Manager select it on the contex menu) with a specific NIC.

Then disable the host (i.e. parent partition) from using that NIC.

(This is the suggested configuration: avoiding both parent and guests all using the same NICs.)

Comment: how do you disable the host from using the NIC for Hyper-V Server (not win2k8)? I didn't see anything in Hyper-V Manager. Is this a command-line operation?

Comment: @qntmfred: I *think* it would be just unbinding protocols from the NIC in the parent partition, but--as this is best practice--would start with the online H-V documentation.